# Compact set in a space with the product topology

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, compactness, locally-compact-groups

I have zero clues on how to solve this:

> "Let be *R* with the discrete topology *d*, and *R* with the eucledian topology *e*, and *X=R x R* with the product topology *t=d x e*. *X* with the topology product *t* is a Hausdorff, locally compacted space. Determine the compact sets of *X*".

I've tried to use Tichonov, but it doesn't cover all the compact sets of *X*, just the ones that are a product of compacte sets. I tried to find a norm that could induce the topology product on X, so i could use othe theorems about finite dimensions spaces, but I struggle with the discrete topolgy that can't be induced by any norm. Any help?

Comment: The. only compact sets in the discrete topology are finite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $K$ be a compact subset of $\Bbb R^2$m endowed with that topology. If $(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2$, let $\pi_1(x,y)=x$. Since $\pi_1$ is continuous, $\pi_1(K)$ is compact, with respect to the discrete topology. Therefore, $\pi_1(K)$ is finite. So, $K=\{x_1\}\times K_1\cup\{x_2\}\times K_2\cup\ldots\cup\{x_n\}\times K_n$, for some subset $\{x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n\}$ of $\Bbb R$ and some subsets $K_1,\ldots,K_n$ of $\Bbb R$. But each $\{x_j\}\times\Bbb R$ is a closed subset of $\Bbb R$, therefore $\{x_j\}\times K_j$ is compact, since it is equal to $(\{x_j\}\times\Bbb R)\cap K$. Therefore, each $K_j$ is compact.

So, the answer is: $K$ is compact, if and only if it can be written as$$\{x_1\}\times K_1\cup\{x_2\}\times K_2\cup\ldots\cup\{x_n\}\times K_n,$$for some compact subsets $K_1,\ldots,K_n$ of $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Did you read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)?

Comment: No, I'm sorry, I don't use this site very often, and I'm not used to the rules. I have a question, the n subsets K1. ..., Kn exist because the projection of K in the other space R is also compact, right?

Comment: No. They exist because asserting that $\pi_1(K)=\{x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n\}$ is the same thins as asserting that $K$ can be written as $\{x_1\}\times K_1\cup\{x_2\}\times K_2\cup\ldots\cup\{x_n\}\times K_n$ for some sets $K_1,K_2,\ldots,K_n$.